# Convert minutes to hours: ,minutes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to convert total minutes to hours and minutes hh:mm..

This is my code

```
    Private Sub TextBox5_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox5.TextChanged
    Dim TotalMinute As Int32

    Dim Minute As Int32
    Dim Hour As Int32

    Try
        TotalMinute = CType(TextBox9.Text, Int32)

        TotalMinute = TotalMinute Mod 1440

        Hour = TotalMinute \ 60
        Minute = TotalMinute Mod 60

        TextBox5.Text = FormatTwoDigits(Hour) & ":" & FormatTwoDigits(Minute)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Sub
    End Try

End Sub

Private Function FormatTwoDigits(ByVal i As Int32) As String
    If 30 > i Then
        FormatTwoDigits = "0" & i.ToString
    Else
        FormatTwoDigits = i.ToString
    End If
End Function
```

This code works fine under 24 hours.. but counts back from 0 after 24...

For example if the input is 1500 minutes it should say 25:00 not 01:00

Comment: You could [convert the number of minutes to a `TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8a3558%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then use [TimeSpan.ToString(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a specified format string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your `TotalMinute = TotalMinute Mod 1440` line, which is saying to get rid of any "day" portion if the total minutes exceeds one day.  (60 minutes = 1 hour, 24 hours = 1 day, therefore 1440 minutes = 1 day.)

Answer (score 5):

Or you could let .Net do the work

```
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TotalMinute)

    Dim s As String = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts.Minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something more like:

```
Private Sub TextBox5_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox5.TextChanged
    Dim TotalMinute As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox9.Text, TotalMinute) Then
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TotalMinute)
        TextBox5.Text = CType(ts.TotalHours, Integer).ToString("00") & ":" & ts.Minutes.ToString("00")
    End If
End Sub
```